# Updation of reputation to the Associated accounts

Tags: support, reputation, area-51

Have a look at below image:

[image]

As you seeing that, when i take my cursor on StackOverflow icon, it shows  [**1577 reputation points**,](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18238/android-enthusiasts) 
but it is actually  [**1584 this time**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379693/paresh-mayani) . (it happens Not for only SO icon, but for all the associated accounts)

I have checked this by refreshing a page many times and even also loggin out many times, as i think it 
may be updated soon.

So, for updation of SO reputation, Meta-SO reputation, SuperUser reputation point to the
area51 or any inter-related site, what is the actual delay time for updation? i think this should be changed to
the associated account quickly as and when the reputation point is updated.

Comment: Where is that? All my mouseovers just show, "reputation score" as the full text. I tried profiles, flairs, posts.....

Comment: @Peter Ajtai check this link: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18238/android-enthusiasts , where my flair is displayed

Comment: Thanks for the link; I see it. That is odd.

Comment: @Peter that's why i like to post to somewhat improvement to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, as these values are denormalized.

If it persists for longer than 48 hours let us know.

Comment: i just marked it...so thought that let me know you, it may helps you